# onNext method doesn't fire on observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a method that returns an observable and calls another method to process the received data. If in my onNext method I call this.addNewData() only it works like a charm.

```
data: BaseData[] = [];


initData() {
 this.dataProvider.getData()
.subscribe(this.addNewData());
}
```

However, if I want to do something more with the data received and use lambda, my method this.addNewData() is being called but as a result my data collection remains empty.

```
initData() {
 this.dataProvider.getData()
.subscribe(
          data => {
            this.addNewData();
            this.showProgressSpinner = false;
            console.log(this.data);
          });
    }
}

  private addNewData() {
    const dataIds = this.data.map(i => i.dataId);
    return fetchedData => fetchedData
      .filter(i => ! dataIds.includes(i.dataId))
      .forEach(i => this.data.push(i));
  }
```

I'm new to Angular and I would like to understand why it happens.

Comment: You're not updating the local value for this.data. before you call `this.addNewData()` make sure you do `this.data = data`.

Comment: @MichaelBeeson I see your point, but in my addNewData() I make sure I update my local value this.data with non-repeatable objects, and if the received data's ids don't include my local collection's ids, I push those objects to my local collection. In first case, it works perfectly, but with the second one the method is being called indeed, but I don't see that `this.data.push(i)`actually did something.

Comment: @juliam Can you explain your second approach better , if possible using code and updating question.and I cant see `fetchedData` declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know that `subscribe()` takes optional three callbacks `next, error, complete`.

The first callback is `next` which requires to have a function which takes an input [this input would be the value emitted by the observable] and returns `void`.

Now let's understand what your addNewData() function returns -

```
private addNewData() {
    const dataIds = this.data.map(i => i.dataId);
    return fetchedData => fetchedData
      .filter(i => ! dataIds.includes(i.dataId))
      .forEach(i => this.data.push(i));
  }
```

It is returning an arrow function which takes an input and returns `void`.

Now come back to your first way to subscribe -

```
initData() {
 this.dataProvider.getData()
.subscribe(this.addNewData());
}
```

Above subscribe is filling `this.data` because `this.addNewData()` returns a function (i.e. arrow function) as expected by the `next` callback of `subscribe()` and the returned function of `this.addNewData()` gets executed which is your following arrow function -

```
fetchedData => fetchedData
      .filter(i => ! dataIds.includes(i.dataId))
      .forEach(i => this.data.push(i));
```

Now hope you got why first subscribe is filling `this.data`

Now come to the second way of subscribing:

```
initData() {
 this.dataProvider.getData()
.subscribe(
          data => {
            this.addNewData();
            this.showProgressSpinner = false;
            console.log(this.data);
          });
    }
}
```

In above subscribe you are already passing a function (i.e. an arrow function) so this function will be executed. Now you are not doing anything with the return function of `this.addNewData()` and that function is having the responsibility to update your collection `this.data`. You should do the following to make it work:

```
initData() {
     this.dataProvider.getData()
    .subscribe(
              data => {
                const retFunc = this.addNewData();
                retFunc(data);
                this.showProgressSpinner = false;
                console.log(this.data);
              });
        }
    }
```

Hope this answers your question.